# Why is perl6 regex ~~ trying to assign to immutable container?

Tags: regex, match, variable-assignment, immutability, raku

I am trying to extract the first name in a regex, but ~~ seems to want to assign to an immutable container. Why so? What did I do wrong?

```
my $test= ' "DOE , JOHN" ';

grammar findReplace {
    regex TOP            { \s* <ptName> \s* }
    regex ptName         { <aName> }
    regex aName          { \" .+? \" }
}

class rsAct {
    method TOP ($/) { make "last name is: " ~ $<ptName>.made; }
    method ptName ($/) { 
        my $nameStr = $/.Str; 
        if $nameStr ~~ m/ \" (<alpha>+) .* \, .* \" / { 
            my $lastName = $/[0];   # I want $/[0] sub-string of outer $/
            make $lastName; 
    }
    }
}

my $m = findReplace.parse($test, actions => rsAct.new);
say $m.made;
```

and the error I got was this:

```
Cannot assign to a readonly variable or a value
  in method ptName at shit.pl line 13
  in regex ptName at shit.pl line 5
  in regex TOP at shit.pl line 4
  in block <unit> at shit.pl line 20
```

I am trying to get a sub-string of the outer $/ that matches a pattern; why would ~~ be an assignment?

Thank you for your help !!!

Comment: You should be using `token` or `rule` most of the time, not `regex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `~~` operator inside a function that already has `$/` defined as an argument. Arguments are read-only by default, so the assignment fails.

It should be enough to use `if $nameStr.match(/your regex/) -> $/ { ... }` instead of the `~~` operator. You will get a fresh `$/` inside the block that'll have the match result you want in it.

Comment: Thank you timotimo. But I already saved the outer $/ in a new variable $nameStr and I was working with this new variable. And what does ~~ try to assign? and assign to what? (to $nameStr?) My limited understanding is making things strange.

Comment: the `~~` operator will assign to the `$/` variable that's currently in scope. That way you can just write `"hello" ~~ /../; say $/` and it'll give you `he`.

Comment: I got it now; but is there an easier way than what I have:     class rsAct {
        method TOP ($/) { make "last name is: " ~ $<ptName>.made; }
        method ptName ($/) { 
     my $nameStr = $/.Str; 
     my $lastName;
     if $nameStr.match(/ \" (<alpha>+) .* \, .* \" /) -> $/ { 
         $lastName = $/[0].Str;
     }
     make $lastName;
        }
    }
    
    my $m = findReplace.parse($test, actions => rsAct.new);
    say $m.made;

Comment: ah, good thing you noticed about the thing with `make`; `make` always acts upon the `$/` in scope, so if you had gone with my suggestion, you would have installed the `$lastname` on the match that was going to be thrown away immediately …